# In app purchase issue ios 7

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine, prime31

For the testing purpose in app purchase is working fine in ios6 but not in ios 7.

While running in xcode for ios6 it shows that the product list has been received, but for ios7 it shows invalid product id.

This is the code I'm using:

```
void Start() 
{ 
    var productIdentifiers = new string[] {"product.100"}; 
    StoreKitBinding.requestProductData( productIdentifiers ); 
} 

void ButtonOne() 
{ 
    bool canMakePayments = StoreKitBinding.canMakePayments(); 
    StoreKitBinding.purchaseProduct( "product.100" , 1 ); 
}
```

Is there any special setting for ios7 which I am missing?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Hers is the code i am using 
`
void Start() 
{ var productIdentifiers = new string[] {"product.100"}; StoreKitBinding.requestProductData( productIdentifiers ); } void ButtonOne() { bool canMakePayments = StoreKitBinding.canMakePayments(); StoreKitBinding.purchaseProduct( "product.100" , 1 );
 }`

Comment: one out of the blue question. How to write code here in comment?

Comment: You can wrap it in `, but just update your question in this case.

Comment: Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036193/phonagap-inapppurchasemanager-plugin-is-not-working-in-ios7           in this question the code is available.Please refer this and give me solution.